# shell script triggering through control-m

Tags: python, unix, scripting, control-m

Generally, i have a shell script which run in Control-m with certain parameters like:

```
sh shell_script_program.sh 'param_1' 'param_2' 'param_3'
```

But, in order to test the program i have to change the parameter values passing to the shell script. So i was editing whole time when ever i want to run the program.

```
sh shell_script_program.sh 'value_1' 'value_2' 'value_3'
sh shell_script_program.sh 'value_1' 'value_3' 'value_4'
```

Is there any way to automate the different set of parameters passed as arguments to the script.

Could you please provide a hint for any solution.

Comment: You can put all values in file and call script using `for loop`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a file with a different set of paramaters like

```
$cat input_param.txt
'param_1' 'param_2' 'param_3'
'value_1' 'value_2' 'value_3'
'value_1' 'value_3' 'value_4'
$
```

and call script in loop

```
while read param; 
do 
   echo ./shell_script_program.sh  ${param} | sh  ;
done < input_param.txt
```

Comment: Thanks but my concern is if second set of passed is invalid scenario, then the third set will not be passed right? The program will fail at the second set of parameter passed. How we can consider that??

Comment: You can submit in background by adding `&`. But tracking script will be difficult. If you can give sample control -M defination. We can update defination based on parameter value and you can deploy those.

Comment: Sure i will provide the details.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wrapper script for this.
Create an environment file with the parameters value.
For eg a .env file with the param values. You can modify the param value by making changes to .env file.
cat .env
param_1=value1
param_2=value2

In the wrapper load the environment file.

Wrapper script Code:
cat wrapper.sh
./.env file

sh shell_script_program.sh 'value_1' 'value_2' 'value_3'

## Check for exit status

echo $?
sh shell_script_program.sh 'param_1' 'param_2' 'param_3'
echo $?

You can execute wrapper script
sh wrapper.sh

Based on exit status you can decide whether to proceed or not.